# How to get average values from specific value type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe:

```
id            value
a       0:3,1:0,2:0,3:4
a       0:0,1:0,2:2,3:0
a       0:0,1:5,2:4,3:0
```

How to get average values of keys in column value?

For example for `0:3,1:0,2:0,3:4` it must be `(0+0+0+3+3+3+3)/7 = 1.71`.

For `0:0,1:0,2:2,3:0` it must be `2+2/2=2`.

For `0:0,1:5,2:4,3:0` it must be `(1+1+1+1+1+2+2+2+2)/9 = 1.44`.

So desired result is:

```
id            value
a              1.71
a              1.66
a              1.44
```

How to do that? Its not a dictionary values, so I dont really understand how to operate with keys and values here

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I tried to turn it into dictionary with  json.loads(). but this error appears: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: there was an error in your calculation

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
g = (df.join(df['value'].str.split(',')
                        .explode()
                        .str.split(':', expand=True)
             .astype(int)
            )
       .assign(value=lambda d: d[0]*d[1])
       .set_index('id', append=True)
       .groupby(level=[0,1])
      )
g['value'].sum()/g[1].sum()
```

output:

```
   id
0  a       1.7143
1  a       2.0000
2  a       1.4444
```

##### how it works:

###### 1- splitting the values and create new columns

```
(df.join(df['value'].str.split(',')
                        .explode()
                        .str.split(':', expand=True)
             .astype(int)
            )
   .assign(value=lambda d: d[0]*d[1])
   .set_index('id', append=True)
)
```

```
      value  0  1
  id             
0 a       0  0  3
  a       0  1  0
  a       0  2  0
  a      12  3  4
1 a       0  0  0
  a       0  1  0
  a       4  2  2
  a       0  3  0
2 a       0  0  0
  a       5  1  5
  a       8  2  4
  a       0  3  0
```

###### 2- computing sum of values and sum of weights to get the mean

```
>>> g['value'].sum()
   id
0  a     12
1  a      4
2  a     13

>>> g[1].sum()
   id
0  a     7
1  a     2
2  a     9 

>>> g['value'].sum()/g[1].sum()
   id
0  a       1.7143
1  a       2.0000
2  a       1.4444
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I am coming to this, but give me a minute ;) I was already fixing the error in the question

Comment: Apart from missing explanation, this looks very complicated. You don't have to solve everything in "one" line

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych please feel free to provide a solution, I am coding the way I like if you don't mind ;)

Comment: @skulldoger please provide the output of `df.to_dict()` (add it to your question)

Comment: thx it worked, your solution is not really efficient though and doesn't work for me on millions rows dataframe

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych and do you have any ideas how to make it efficiently for cases when there are millions of rows?

Comment: @skulldoger you did not say that you had millions of rows, that said my quick test gave me ~740ms for 100k rows, so it's quite good. Can you provide a better example?

Comment: @mozway yeah my bad, it has millions of rows. example is good one, its just very large. just imagine that in that same dataframe example there are millions of rows, not three

Comment: How long did it take to run on your data?